# ZipFile bad directory structure

Tags: python, archive, python-zipfile

I try make some scripts which helps me zip a file from selected dir.

I have:

```
import sys
import os
import zipfile

source_dir = "C:\\myDir\\yourDir\\"
zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:\\myDir\\yourDirZip.zip","w",allowZip64=True)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for f in files:
        zip.write(os.path.join(root,f))

zip.close()
```

After execution, in `yourDirZip.zip` is:

```
myDir/
    yourDir/
      ...
```

I expect directly only `yourDir` or even only content of `yourDir`

Have you any ideas on how I can get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `arcname` parameter in the `write` method:

```
import sys
import os
import zipfile

source_dir = "C:\\myDir\\yourDir"
zip = zipfile.ZipFile("C:\\myDir\\yourDirZip.zip","w",allowZip64=True)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for f in files:
        zip.write(os.path.join(root,f), arcname=f)

zip.close()
```